# How to force Jgit to use SSH instead of HTTPs?

Tags: java, git, ssh, jgit

I am trying to clone a git repo with submodules, but the problem is inside the .gitmodules the url is in https. I don't want to use CredentialProvider. I've tried using this :

```
session.setConfig("url.git@github.com:.insteadof","https://github.com/");
```

This is not working, it is still trying to use https. Can you please help me with this? I am new to JGit.